# Pass list as argument in neo4j using Python

Tags: python, list, neo4j

I am trying to run this query in which the parameter is a list:

```
codes = ["123","234"]
query = graph.run("""
     MATCH (n:NAME)
     where n.codes = "{}"
     RETURN return n.commonName as commonName""".format(codes))
```

I am trying to pass the "codes" as parameter to Neo4j query. This throws an error that "list is not readable in the query"

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you have quotes around the list in the query and why are you using string injection instead of query parameters?

Comment: Do you mean the value of codes is a list type? Not codes in any of the items on the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code that I am using on my testing:

```
from py2neo import Graph 
session = Graph("http://localhost:7474", auth=("neo4j", "*****"))
//create a dictionary of key:value
param = {"codes":["Angy","Rodney"]}
//use $<dict_key> in your query. For ex: $codes
query = """
     MATCH (n:Customer)
     where n.Name in $codes
     RETURN n"""
//Run the result
result = session.run(query, parameters=param).data() 
//Below are my debugging/print to check what is inside the node

print ("What is data type of result? ", type(result))
print ("What is the data type of each item? ", type(result[0]))
print ("What are the keys of the dictionary? ", result[0].keys())
print ("What is the class of the node? ", type(result[0].get('n')))
print ("How to access the first node? ", result[0].get('n'))
print ("How to access values inside the node? ", result[0].get('n',{}).get('Name'))
 
Result:
What is data type of result?  <class 'list'>
What is the data type of each item?  <class 'dict'>
What are the keys of the dictionary?  dict_keys(['n'])
What is the class of the node?  <class 'py2neo.data.Node'>
How to access the first node?  (_327:Customer {Latitude: 48.509075, Longitude: -2.7383235, Name: 'Angy'})
How to access values inside the node?  Angy
```